# navbar-toggler dont open or open and close bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

this code works perfectly in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/ but when I copy it, the menu does not open, or it opens and closes

```
 <div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Flavio </a>
    <button
     class="navbar-toggler"
     type="button"
     data-toggle ="collapse"
     data-target  = "#toggleMobileMenu"
     aria-controls = "toggleMobileMenu"
     aria-expanded = "false "
     aria-lable = "toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggleMobileMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong data attribute names. This comes up weekly on SO. Be sure you're following the correct documentation. Version 4 and 5 are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following links to your HTML file and it will work properly.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Just Like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Flavio </a>
    <button
     class="navbar-toggler"
     type="button"
     data-toggle ="collapse"
     data-target  = "#toggleMobileMenu"
     aria-controls = "toggleMobileMenu"
     aria-expanded = "false "
     aria-lable = "toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggleMobileMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```